# Haskell coproducts and data record field restrictions

Tags: haskell

Suppose we have the following type definition:

```hs
data P = PA | PB
```

(doesn't matter the structure of PA or PB)

Then, we can define some other record types like this (case 1):

```hs
data C1 = C1 { field :: P } -- this is fine
```

but sometimes you need to define more constrained type of field (case 2):

```hs
data C2 = C2 { field :: PA } -- won't compile because PA is a data constructor
```

What is the most natural and idiomatic way in Haskell to solve cases like these? 
I'm trying to avoid over-complicated or boilerplate solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most natural and idiomatic way is to make `PA` (and possibly `PB`) its own type:

```
data PAtype = ...
data PBtype = ...
data P = PA PAtype | PB PBtype

data C1 = C1 { field :: P }
data C2 = C2 { field :: PAtype }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is how I'm doing it right now, and have a lot of similar data constructors and names which I was trying to fix somehow.

Comment: Then you should probably put THAT in your question. Something like "I am aware of the "standard" way, but is there a better one? And here's what I don't like about the standard way."

Comment: I wasn't sure that this is really a "standard" way. 
I'll accept this of course, if nobody else comes up with a shorter version.

Answer (score 8):

There is a technique which I have never had the occasion to use in practice, of tagging a type with the constructor used.  It's worth a try.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

data Tag = TA | TB

-- data P = PA | PB
data P t where
    PA :: P TA
    PB :: P TB
```

Then you can take a general `P t` if your function works on any constructor, but you can also constrain:

```
f :: P t -> Bool
f PA = True
f PB = False

g :: P TA -> ()
g PA = ()
-- PB case is unnecessary (and impossible to write)
```

It gets a little awkward if you want to return something with an indeterminate tag.  You can either use an existential

```
data AnyP where
    AnyP :: P t -> AnyP

h :: Bool -> AnyP
h True = AnyP PA
h False = AnyP PB
```

Or you can use the "CPS" encoding of existentials to avoid introducing a new type:

```
h' :: Bool -> (forall t. P t -> z) -> z
h' True c = c PA
h' False c = c PB
```

I think it's also likely that this is overkill and you just need to abstract a little differently.  When in doubt, try adding a type parameter.

Comment: I think you have a typo: should be `PA :: P TA` instead of `PA :: PA TA` and same with `PB`

Comment: But this kinda looks like the exact same amount of boilerplate to me, no?

Comment: This is a really interesting tag technique, thanks for sharing.  I agree with @FyodorSoikin, from the view of boilerplate it looks about the same, but still something I haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish this and provide the complete solution, the best option so far is:

(extending the answer of Fyodor a bit):

```hs
module Test 
  P, mkPA, mkPB, PAT ( PAT ), PBT ( PBT )
where

data PAT = PAT
data PBT = PBT
data P = PA PAT | PB PBT

-- Auxiliary type class to use constructors of particular data types, 
-- hide intermediate data constructors (PA, PB) from external modules.
-- In this example, they seem trivial and redundant, 
-- but for complex data types they might be really handy

class IsPA a where
  mkPA :: PAT -> a

class IsPB a where
  mkPB :: PBT -> a

instance IsPA P where
  mkPA = PA

instance IsPB P where
  mkPB = PB

instance IsPA PAT where
  mkPA = id

instance IsPB PBT where
  mkPB = id
```

And you can use them now as:

```hs
data C1 = C1 { field :: P }
data C2 = C2 { field :: PAT }

testC1 = C1 { field = mkPA PAT }
testC2 = C2 { field = mkPA PAT }
```

I still haven't found a less cumbersome option than this. I was hoping that I just didn't know some language extension to solve it more effectively.